# PropTypes causing form to refresh onSubmit redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

When PropTypes is used with component, the form submission causes refreshing of the page and the handleSubmit of redux-form not working.

For eg:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

@reduxForm({ form: 'loginForm' })
export default class Login extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
        requesting: PropTypes.bool,
        errMsg: PropTypes.string,
    };

    static defaultProps = {
        handleSubmit: _noop,
        requesting: false,
        errMsg: null,
    };

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return(
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                <Field component={FormInput} name="username" />
                <Field component={FormInput} name="password" />
                <button type="submit">submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
    onSubmit = values => { console.log(values) }; // This is not working as expected and after submitting causes page reload with both username and password passed as queryString.
}

// or even like below, with proptypes declared outside.

MyForm.propTypes = {
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
    requesting: PropTypes.bool,
    errMsg: PropTypes.string,
};

MyForm.defaultProp = {
    handleSubmit: _noop,
    requesting: false,
    errMsg: null,
};
```

But when I remove the proptypes code, it works perfectly.

Environment Details:

```
redux-form: 7.3.0,
Browser: Chrome,
Node: v8.9.4
```

I am suspecting the error may be in webpack configuration. But I don't know exactly.
I am using the following three plugins.

```
transform-class-properties
transform-object-rest-spread
transform-decorators-legacy
```

Comment: Because when you remove PropTypes everything works fine does not necessarily mean PropTypes are the culprit.

Comment: You need to provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I did my max. If you have any idea about the issue, pls help me to resolve it.

Comment: @brandNew Yeah that's why I added things about webpack config. Maybe that's were the root cause is.

Comment: @AnandKS I think that issue is not related to `proptypes`... what happens after submit?

Comment: After submit, Page reloads and the values are passed to URL as query string. Like a normal HTML form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem with the above code. The problem is the defaultProp I gave to `handleSubmit` as lodash's `_noop`. That overrides the function and cancels its default action.
Once I remove the defaultProp for `handleSubmit` it works as expected.

But the thing is, I have used `_noop` as defaultProp for `handleSubmit` before. That was working fine. But all of a sudden it's not working.

Even I tried setting `null` as defaultProp for `handleSubmit` but it throws an error as `handleSubmit is not a function`.

In the end, handleSubmit is a prop from redux-form. So I found we should not put defaultProp for that.